# AWS: Running scheduled Python code to update a static S3 page

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I just set up a static S3 bucket with a <1MB json file on it. I'd like to update this file once a day using a Python script that exports the json file. What's the best way to go about this in the AWS environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run a python script on your computer that uses the AWS Python SDK ([boto3](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) to upload to S3. Run it via cron, if preferred.

If you don't want to rely on your computer, then you could run an [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) script on a [schedule](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html). Your Lambda script can be written in Python, and can use the boto3 SDK.